# How can I add Websphere 6.1 server/runtime to Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-6.1

I'm currently using RAD 7.0.x.x but I would like to switch to Eclipse. As far as I managed to Google, there's no way to do it (there is an example which shows it's possible by making a Genreic Server/Runtime, but that option is not available in Eclipse Galileo 3.5.2.). I could try Helios, but before downloading and installing would like to find out if this is even possible (as far as I know, it's possible to use WebSphere 6.0, but not 6.1/7).

Comment: @duffymo, RAD builds on Eclipse, so it is familiar.  Might be important.

Comment: Not familiar enough, apparently.  And I'm offering the information purely for its own sake.  The OP can do what they wish with it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice but we have to use either Eclipse or RSA so I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can not, the last supported version is 6.0.